# type_info error in boost serialization

Tags: android, c++, serialization, boost

It becomes a link error to serialize the "map" in boost serialization.

```
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>

map<int, int> map;
ofstream ofs(testpass);
{
    archive::binary_oarchive oar(ofs);
    oar << map;
}
ofs.close();
```

Link Error:

> boost::serialization::typeid_system::extended_type_info_typeid_0::is_less_than(boost::serialization::extended_type_info const&) const:libs/serialization/src/extended_type_info_typeid.cpp:56: error: undefined reference to 'std::type_info::before(std::type_info const&) const'

When you change the `"string"` or `"int"` instead of `map<int, int>`, the errors are cleared.
The version of boost is 1.53.

What is wrong?

Comment: Either your C++ Standard Library implementation is missing that function, or you're not linking with it; or perhaps you're building with RTTI disabled. I'm afraid I don't know enough about Android to guess which, or how to fix it.

Comment: I add the following to the Application.mk  "APP_STL := gnustl_shared", Error is no longer!! Thank you!!

Comment: I wonder why that is.